# Hosts file on server with dynamic DNS?

Tags: hostname, hosts, domain, dynamic-dns

I am setting up a RHEL-based server that is associated with dynamic DNS from DynDNS, with a domain of, say, "abc.dyndns.org" that is dynamically updated with the server's IP address.

I have read that in order to ensure access to your server's services, you need to have at least the following in your /etc/hosts:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain   localhost
>
> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx redhatbox.yourcompany.com redhatbox

Where "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" is whatever IP address your server has, and "redhatbox" would be the name of the computer. So here are my questions:

(1) Because my server has an IP that is dynamically assigned by my ISP's DHCP, there is no one IP I can put in place of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, what should I do in this case?

(2) Should I simply replace "redhatbox.yourcompany.com" with my DynDNS domain "abc.dyndns.org"? And replace the "redhatbox" alias with "abc"?

If anyone can explain all this for a novice like me that would be great. Thank you very much for your detailed answers and patience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some context:

When a program asks your machine to resolve a hostname into a IP address it looks into your `/etc/hosts` and, if not found, it then makes a DNS query.

You don't need to keep a non-loopback IP address on it. You can just usually keep the `localhost` entries and an alias.

See, that's my `/etc/hosts` contents:

```
[braga@coleman ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1       coleman.jazz coleman
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost
```

`coleman.jazz` or `coleman` (named for the musician, Ornette Coleman) is just an alias for my machine.

Direct answers:

1. Just leave it out.
2. You can replace it wherever you want to. it's just an alias. You can even replace it with `www.google.com` (and `www.google.com` on your machine will point up to your own machine).

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your clear explanation and especially direct answers!